# how to define line color and show two legend block in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df like below and I would like to generate a plot :

```
df<-structure(list(AVAL = c(36.9, 37.2, 36.5, 36.7222222222222, 36.9, 
36.9, 36.9, 37.2, 36.9), ADY = c(-9, -1, 1, 8, 15, 15, 15, 22, 
35), PARAMCD = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "VSTEMP", class = "factor"), Flag = c(NA, NA, NA, 
8, 15, 15, 15, 22, NA), AESER = c(NA, NA, NA, "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "Y", NA)), row.names = 546:554, class = "data.frame")

ggplot(data =df)+
    geom_line(data=df[!is.na(df$AVAL),],aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL, color = PARAMCD, yaxs="d", xaxs="d"),size=0.8)+
    geom_point(data=df[!is.na(df$AVAL),], aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL))+
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=Flag, color=AESER),lty='dashed')
```

My plot is look like following:

[image]

I wonder whether it is possible to define the vertical line as `black for AESER=="N", and red for AESER=="Y"`? Also for the legend, is it possible to just show the one for vertical lines? or is it a better way to present the legend, maybe one block for measure item `VSTERM`, and then another one for `AESER: Y|N`? Could anyone guide me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1:

In case a single legend for the vertical line and the geom_line `Y/N/VSTEMP` is enough, this should do it:

```
ggplot(data =df[!is.na(df$AVAL),], aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL))+
    geom_line(aes(color = 'PARAMCD')), size=0.8) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=Flag, color=AESER), lty='dashed') +
    scale_color_manual(name = "legend_name", values = c(N = "black", Y = "red", VSTEMP = "green"))
```

### Option 2:

In the case of a single legend for the vertical line `Y/N`:

```
ggplot(data =df[!is.na(df$AVAL),], aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL))+
  geom_line(color='green', size=0.8)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=Flag, color=AESER), lty='dashed') +
  scale_color_manual(name = "legend_name", values = c(N = "black", Y = "red"))
```

output:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks. I got `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided.`. It seems like it would ask me to define `PARAMCD` as well.

Comment: You can use `scale_color_manual(name = "legend_name", values = c(N = "black", Y = "red", VSTEMP = 'blue'))` then.

Comment: Thanks so much. When I use this,, I only saw dots instead of line  for PARAMCD. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way. Add a `scale_color_manual` with the colors you want in the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df[!is.na(df$AVAL), ], aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = PARAMCD), size = 0.8) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Flag, color = AESER), 
             linetype = 'dashed') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("N" = "black", "Y" = "red", "VSTEMP" = "green"))
```

[image]

---

### Edit

Plot to answer the requests in comments, only `AESER` in the legend.

```
ggplot(data = df[!is.na(df$AVAL), ], aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL)) +
  geom_line(color = "green", size = 0.8) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Flag, color = AESER), linetype = 'dashed') +
  scale_color_manual(name = "AESER", values = c("N" = "black", "Y" = "red"))
```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to show legend for `AESER` only? As right now the legend looks strange. N and Y is not an item for PARAMCD

Comment: Also, `data= df[!is.na(df$AVAL)` is only for solid line, vertical line might have `NA` for `AVAL`. If we add `+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("N" = "black", "Y" = "red", "VSTEMP" = "green"))` right behind my old codes, it seems the solid line disperse. What should I do?

Comment: @Stataq To not have the solid line in the legend disperse put `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_vline`. As for having only `AESER` in the legend, I will edit, but it's basically @noan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69456584/8245406).

Comment: Thanks.  `show.legend = FALSE in geom_vline` seems removed the verticle line in the legend. Is it possible to show vertical line for AESER and solid line for VSTEMP? Also, is it possible to order the legend, such as `VSTEMP, Y, N`